# In UINavigationController, I have to use two rightBarButtonItem with Image in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, rightbarbuttonitem

In my Application, i have to use two `rightBarButtonItem` in `UINavigationController` with image in swift 3.0, I'm posting the Image below,

[image]

In the given image, i'm very worried about Create Account and Login rightBarbuttonItem's image, how do i add those images and the border between the buttons exactly like the given sample.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: you can achieve it by add UIButton & image & lable too

Comment: @iPatel I have tried but failed to do that in swift with correct syntax.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra The simplest way is to create one UIView and put all this thing along with it and then create baritem using customView init

Comment: @AbhishekMitra - Yes as per Nirav's suggestion best way is hide navigation bar for this viewcontroller and make custom navigation bar (by use of uiview) as you want.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra No need to hide the navigationBar, simply create the barbutton item from view an set it as rightItem

Comment: @NiravD What i'm trying in my code is to adding a subview in a uinavigation bar, but I'm doubting, if it is possible, your thought makes sense to me, but will you provide me some swift code, today is my first day in swift :/ with a complex designed project.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra Have you create xib, if yes then first simply create one UIView design for your create Account and login button with image and separator if this will done inform here

Comment: @NiravD Sir, Anand post his answer and I wanted the same what he posted there. thanks for your guidance too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What my work around is to add a UIView inside of navigation bar's title view and expend it as much as required and then you can place as much control as you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Anand Its working,  :) Nirav tried the same with his Guidance, but i failed to do that, Your explanation is appreciable :)
http://oi66.tinypic.com/2a78zug.jpg

Comment: Happy coding :)